# how to solve the java error for File: (no associated file) [line: (no source location)]

Tags: windows

I'm learning java as you can probably see. I'm stuck on the first lesson I can't compile it for this error.

```
1./*
2.Java Hello World example.
3.*/
4. 
5.public class HelloWorldExample{
6. 
7.  public static void main(String args[]){
8. 
9.    /*
10.    Use System.out.println() to print on console.
11.    */
12.    System.out.println("Hello World !");
13.  
14.  }
15. 
16.}
17. 
18./*
19. 
20.OUTPUT of the above given Java Hello World Example would be :
21. 
22.Hello World !
23. 
24.*/  

1 error found:
File: (no associated file)  [line: (no source location)]
Error: Compile exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/IrritantSet
```

please help this blind fool find the associated file, Thanks

Comment: What!? IrritantSet??? XD

Answer (score 0):

You have misconfigured your JRE in Eclipse. It'll work if you run it outside eclipse or fix your Eclipse JRE settings.

Comment: This comment is to contact you directly. I need basic programing advice from someone and maybe some "complete" codes to try out but above all else i need for someone to fill in the blanks in the lines. I dont know how to change my JRE settings or if i'm missing a string file or not. If you feel inclined to through some simple "complete" but VERY basic java programs with "java for dummies" advice at me i would be so greatful. I am looking on the net for step by step instructions but i dont even know all the right terms. My e-mail is >davidyankee33@yahoo.com<  Thanks for any help.

Comment: @DrizztDuOrden the code you have is fine. There are beginners instructions at http://www.freejavaguide.com/corejava1.htm - all you need to do is to [download and install a JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), [put it in the PATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and you're good to go.